# How can I change the relative position of an image in a <div> tag

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to vertically align and image within a horizontal menu bar. Ideally i want to set the padding/margin of the image using inline CSS.

However, when i try to add a margin-top or padding-top this moves down all my links as well as the image. I just want to move the image down for cosmetic reasons.

```
<style>
body {
background: #000000 url("/images/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;
width: 1000px;
}

#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}
#menu a:hover {
color: red;}    
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="menu"><a href="/who-is-it-for.html">WHO IS IT FOR</a><a href="/contact.html">BOOK NOW</a><a href="/team-building-locations.html">LOCATIONS</a>

<a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/logo-menu.png" alt="home" width="90" onMouseOver="this.src='/images/logo-menu-rollover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='/images/logo-menu.png';"></a>

<a href="/team-building-photos.html">PHOTOS</a><a href="/team-building-pricing.html">PRICING</a><a href="/team-building-locations.html">NEWS</a><a href="/faqs.html">FAQ</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `vertical-align: top` for `a` element.

```html
<style>
body {
background: #000000 url("/images/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;
width: 1000px;
}
 
#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
vertical-align: top /* added this option */
}

#menu a:hover {
color: red
}

img {
  margin-top: 50px /* whatever you want */
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="menu"><a href="/who-is-it-for.html">WHO IS IT FOR</a><a href="/contact.html">BOOK NOW</a><a href="/team-building-locations.html">LOCATIONS</a>
 
<a href="/index.html"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100/4B89DA/FFFFFF" alt="home" width="90" onMouseOver="this.src='/images/logo-menu-rollover.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='/images/logo-menu.png';"></a>

<a href="/team-building-photos.html">PHOTOS</a><a href="/team-building-pricing.html">PRICING</a><a href="/team-building-locations.html">NEWS</a><a href="/faqs.html">FAQ</a></div>
```